# New to arduino, help wiring relay

Tags: programming, relay, wires, switch

I am new to arduino and need some help. I just baught light bars for my jeep and wiring harnesses with them, the harnesses come with buttons and I wanted to replace the button and have them controlled on my phone. The harnesses come with a relay and a fuse and a button all 12v, How would i go about using my raspberry pi or udoo x86(which has built in adruino) to basically replace the rocker switch so i can then turn things on and off without needing to have actual switches.

Comment: a simple MCU can do it. no need to have a computer for this. use Arduino Nano or Mini

Comment: Google: "Arduino relay" and look at the pretty pictures.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to mess with the harnesses electronic, you can bridge the buttons using a MOSFET, which can be directly controlled by Arduino or the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

To drive a relay you'll need a transistor (a MOSFET is a good choice) and you'll need a diode across the relay coils to protect the transistor from the reverse current pulse when you remove power from the relay coils.

As Majenko says, if you Google "Arduino relay" you'll find lots of articles covering the topic. (And if you use a digital output line from your PI the exact same circuit will work.)

This MOSFET is a good option for switching high current loads with a 5V logic signal:

https://www.adafruit.com/product/355

The diode will need to be a power diode that can handle your voltage/current needs. You'll need to figure out how much current your light bar uses, and then I'd suggest a diode that can handle twice that much current (at 12V) for a margin of safety.

Comment: Re “handle twice that much current (at 12V)”: Not at 12 V. It should handle the current when forward biased, and the voltage when reverse biased.

Comment: why not MOSFET only

Comment: An inductive coil like a relay coil dumps a large surge of reverse current when you remove power from it. (sometimes called "flyback current".) That is enough to destroy a transistor, so you need a diode to protect the transistor.

Comment: how do i see how much current the lights bar uses, can i just use the volts and amps that the relay says on it? also things say i need a resistor, how do i choose that also.

Comment: http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-output-devices/tip122-arduino-relay-tutorial/ this is the circuit i think i will use with the mosfet, does each mosfet use a different ground or all the same

Comment: I meant without the relay

Comment: @Juraj, sure, you could skip the relay and drive the light bar directly without the relay. In that case it would be a straight inductive load and you wouldn't need a protection diode. To the OP, it would be simpler to get rid of the relay from your harness and control the lights directly with a MOSFET like the one I linked in my answer. You can drive that MOSFET's gate directly with a logic line from a PI or Arduino, and it will switch a large amount of current (although you'll need a heat-sink for larger current loads - see the specs.)